# Is it possible to specify a pattern for an AWS role Trust Relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to allow some roles from a different account to assume a role in my account. I don't want to specify the roles one by one, because they're prone to change frequently.

I came up with this policy for the Trust Relationship, which should allow any role which name ends with `_my_suffix`, but it doesn't work (access is denied):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NR_A:root"
      },
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NR_A:role/*_my_suffix"
        }
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

On the other hand, this policy works but it's too open, as it allows any user/role in account A to assume my role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NR_A:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, is there any way to allow only a set of roles without being explicitly specified?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I encountered the same use-case recently. None of the responses resolved this for me.

Charli, your original solution is valid but I needed some tweaks get it to work, namely, I needed to replace 'ArnLike' with 'stringLike' and switch 'aws:SourceArn' to use 'aws:PrincipalArn':

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/test-role-name-*"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did it work? Ugh, for me is not clear which `Condition` to use. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.. this saved my day.. any idea on where to find the list of conditions and variable that can be used.

Comment: This is a savior! Wonder if there's any reason to not include this to AWS docs but explicitly state that it's impossible?

Comment: @HiteshGarg https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

Comment: I had the condition of:

`"ArnLike": {`
`"aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/my-role*"`
`}`

And that didn't work for me until I changed  it up and use **StringLike** and **aws:PrincipalArn**.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use wildcard in the trust policy except `"Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }` . The reason being when you specify an identity as Principal, you must use the full ARN since IAM translates to the unique ID e.g. AIDAxxx (for IAM user) or AROAxxx (for IAM role). Below is the from [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#Principal_specifying):

> If your Principal element in a role trust policy contains an ARN that
>   points to a specific IAM user, then that ARN is transformed to the
>   user's unique principal ID when the policy is saved. This helps
>   mitigate the risk of someone escalating their privileges by removing
>   and recreating the user. You don't normally see this ID in the
>   console, because there is also a reverse transformation back to the
>   user's ARN when the trust policy is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to an issue with delegating access to trusting account(your account) and not the trusted account(_my_suffix - AWS account). These are few things that you can check in the following URL.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to rely ONLY in the permissions set in the roles that belong to ACCOUNT_NR_A, as any user can create a policy granting himself the usage of my role.Actually that's why I want to use a patter-like policy.