# AssumeRole trusted entities to a specific lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

I have a lambda that needs quite a lot of permissions because it automatically kills temporary resources, so I have assigned the managed policy `AdministratorAccess`. What I want to do is to restrict this role to only be assumed a specific lambda function. I have tried to set a condition on `sts:AssumeRole`, but when trying to assign this role to a lambda I get an error:

> Your role is not ready, or cannot be assumed by Lambda. Please wait up
>   to a minute and try again.

Maybe relevant; the lambda and role CF-stack is deployed with CodePipeline that uses a role `CICD-Pipeline`. Have anyone done this? This is what I have so far:

```
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: common-delete-stack-Role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
            Action: [sts:AssumeRole]
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:common-delete-stack
      ManagedPolicyArns: [arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess]
```

I've also tried this Condition with the same result.

```
StringEquals:
  lambda:FunctionArn: !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:common-delete-stack
```

Comment: Might be relevant: [Is it possible to specify a pattern for an AWS role Trust Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56145538/174777)

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. It seems to me that roles assuming roles and services that assumes roles work a bit differently?

Comment: Trust Policies are a bit of a mystery. Keep trying various options, otherwise this is a good example of how subscribing to AWS Support could save you a lot of time.

Comment: Have you tried using `ArnEquals` instead of `StringEquals` in the Condition?

Comment: @MikePatrick Yes, unfortunately without success.