# Restricting access to an AWS resource using a specific pattern of AWS roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

I want all roles of my AWS account having a specific pattern to be able to access a Secrets Manager secret. I know I can use `Condition` block and wildcard matching for that.

However, the `Principal` field is **required** in a resource policy.

Will the following policy restrict access to just the roles matching the pattern?

```json
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/my_role_*"
        }
      },
      "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:root" },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678910:secret:some-secret-1234",
      "Sid": "rp1"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: As per this one it will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429229/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-pattern-for-an-aws-role-trust-relationship.  You can also solve it with  IAM User or Role tags to control that.

aws:PrincipalTag can be used to create IAM policy statements.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the wildcard "All Principal": `{"AWS": "*"}`. The combination of a same-account Account Principal + wildcard condition works in role *trust* policies<sup>1</sup> but apparently not in *resource* policies<sup>2</sup>.

---

The [IAM docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-roles) say:

> You can specify the role principal as the principal in a resource-based policy or create a broad-permission policy [with a wildcard Principal] that uses the `aws:PrincipalArn` condition key.

Because the condition contains the account number, the All Principal is no more permissive than the Account Principal would be.   Also, because the policy is always tied to a specific secret resource, the wildcard `"*"` Resoure is no more permissive than the secret name.  Finally, while an `ArnLike` condition [is not always equivalent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_ARN) to `StringLike`, it is identical in this case.

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {  "AWS" : "*" },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678910:secret:some-secret-1234",
    "Condition" : {
      "ArnLike" : {
        "aws:PrincipalArn" : "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/my_role_*"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

---

1. See the wildcard permissions section of the AWS blog post [How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/) for a trust policy example.
2. Error using a Lambda role + secrets manager resource policy with a same-account Account Principal:  `...no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action`.

Comment: I have tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143142/condition-in-aws-resource-policy-not-allowing-lambda-to-access-secrets-manager-s) and it does not seem to be working

Comment: @pkaramol My answer works as documented for me.  Double check your Role and Secret ID ARN spellings.  Ensure your Secret ARN has the right 6 random digits appended.  Consider debugging with wildcards instead of ARNs to prove the principle.  Then narrow.

Comment: It works without any explicit identity policy attached on the `lambda`, right? just with the above resource policy?

Comment: @pkaramol ;) Correct - only logging permissions in the role's identity policy.  As expected, if I \*deliberately mis-spell\* the Role or Secret ARN in the resource policy, I get the dreaded `no identity-based policy allows` error.