# Condition in AWS resource policy not allowing lambda to access Secrets Manager Secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam, identity-management

I have the following resource policy on a Secrets Manager secret

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "rp1",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : ["*"]
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1111111111111111:secret:my-secret-VH7Qgf",
    "Condition" : {
      "ArnLike" : {
        "aws:PrincipalArn" : "arn:aws:iam::1111111111111111:role/my-role*"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

My lambda has the following Executor role arn; `arn:aws:iam::1111111111111111:role/my-role-foo`

However its execution fails with:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1111111111111111:assumed-role/my-secret/my-lambda is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: my-secret because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action",
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

An AWS resource policy **cannot** grant permissions on the attached resource.

Hence, even if you have allowed "actions" in resource policy it does not mean that the resource (*consumer*) trying to access has the privilege.

For the resource(*consumer*) to have access, it needs permissions granted via AWS IAM Role attached to it.

Therefore, you need to have `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` as a part of the AWS IAM Role `arn:aws:iam::1111111111111111:role/my-role-foo` that is attached to the AWS Lambda function.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Although not 100% sure, I think this is limited by the `Condition` statements that can be applied to Secrets Manager.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awssecretsmanager.html) indicate that the `StringLike` nor the `ArnLike` can be applied.